# maven ant run plugin changes jar

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar

I have successfully created pom.xml that uses maven-antrun-plugin with step that compiles *.app file and generates jar file. This jar is later on used during next build life cycle. The problem is when this 3rd jar is installed to maven local repository, that jar is changed and does not contain original structure like package,manifest,etc. Maven will change it.
Here is the POM.xml file that is used for creating jar:

```
<artifactId>hellojavaworld</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <property environment="env" />
                            <property name="appname" value="hellojavaworld" />
                            <echoproperties />
                            <exec dir="" executable="respawn.exe" searchpath="true">
                                <arg value="${basedir}\src\main\java\${appname}.app" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The compiler respawn.exe creates hellojavaworld.jar which is correct. When I execute

> mvn clean install

it creates hellojavaworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in my .../.m2/repository but this is not the original/correct jar file. It is changed by Maven and does not work for later dependency.

> Question is:

How to tell the Maven to use or copy the correct jar file to local repository?

Comment: What does respawn.exe do? You are saying it creates the jar file already...than the given packaging `jar` is wrong, cause in this case the build life cylcle will run through (compile, test. jar packaging etc.) which results in a jar file which is created by maven and not by respawn.exe...If you just want to create the jar file by respawn.exe just use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) instead of using a jar life cycle binding...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I need to call the respawn.exe to create a jar that is later on used in the project build. I am not sure that mavev helper plugin can do that. The ant run plugin was used due to a possibility to call exe program. The Maven helper plugin just solves dependency. Do you agree?

Comment: There might be solution to use Maven install plugin. I created the jar using the AntRun plugin and then used mvn install:install-file command and the jar file in local repository was correct!!! Let me try this.